# Microsoft.CppCommon.targets: The specified task executable "cmd.exe" could not be run. Because the file contains a virus

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Suddenly my project has stopped to build. I don't even know where should I look to resolve the error?
What I've done I scanned my PC on viruses, added exception in Windows Defender for `cmd.exe`.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5):
> error MSB6003: The specified task executable "cmd.exe" could not be
> run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Operation did
> not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or
> potentially unwanted software

Comment: Please provide more information. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT sorry if the information I provided is not enough but I can't give you more. As I said I did not even know where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In event log I found a suspicious message from RAV antivirus. The problem was in RAV Antivirus. Somehow(?) it got installed on my machine and it was blocking `cmd.exe` from running.